# npm package untyped@1.4.1 ERROR Cannot find module './shared/untyped.a47b2336.cjs'

Tags: npm, nuxt.js

I'm learning a nuxt project, which uses `nuxt@3.0.0-rc.3`.
When I finished `yarn install`，I typed `yarn run dev`，but I got error message as below:

```bash
$ yarn run dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ nuxt dev --open
Nuxt 3.0.0-rc.3                                                                                                                                                         2:13:18 PM

 ERROR  Cannot find module './shared/untyped.a47b2336.cjs'                                                                                                              2:13:18 PM
Require stack:
- ~/mycode/nuxt-project-clone/node_modules/untyped/dist/index.d.cts
```

I checked the dependency relation:

```bash
$ npm ls untyped
~/mycode/nuxt-project-clone
├─┬ @nuxtjs/tailwindcss@5.3.5
│ └─┬ @nuxt/kit@3.9.3
│   └── untyped@1.4.1
└─┬ nuxt@3.0.0-rc.3
  ├─┬ @nuxt/schema@3.9.3
  │ └── untyped@1.4.1 deduped
  └── untyped@0.4.7
```

then explored the `untyped` package:

```bash
$ cat node_modules/untyped/dist/index.d.cts
import { I as InputObject, S as Schema, a as SchemaDefinition } from './shared/untyped.a47b2336.cjs';
export { F as FunctionArg, c as InputValue, b as JSType, J as JSValue, R as ResolveFn, T as TypeDescriptor } from './shared/untyped.a47b2336.cjs';
....
```

and the package does not have `./shared/untyped.a47b2336.cjs`

```bash
$ ls node_modules/untyped/dist/shared/
untyped.84362cee.cjs
untyped.a47b2336.d.cts
untyped.a47b2336.d.mts
untyped.a47b2336.d.ts
untyped.b44a3145.cjs
untyped.bd7ca8a5.mjs
```

But I did run the project successfully yesterday. I just removed the node_modules and re-installed the packages, and it turns to have this error.

Did the 'untyped@1.4.1' package change overnight?

Answer (score 1):

`untyped: 1.4.1` is causing this,

**Solution 1:**

add following line to your package.json:

```json
  "resolutions": { "untyped": "=1.4.0" },
```

The resolutions field in a package. json file allows you to specify an exact version of a package that should be used in your project, even if the package is not directly required by your project

**Solution 2:**

```json
"overrides": {
  "untyped": "1.4.0"
},
```

**UPDATE:**

[Version 1.4.2](https://github.com/unjs/untyped/releases) was released and the bug was fixed

Comment: I used solution 1, but got another error:

`ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  nuxt.options.buildModules is not iterable`                                                                
  

I did run this project successfully some days ago, why could it turn to be like this 